# How to call function at other class in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing in Objective-C.

I create the two file call **`AAA.m`** and **`BBB.m`**.

**1.** In the **`AAA.m`** , I call a function **`readValue`** in **`BBB.m`** and send a **`NSString`**.

**2.** In the **`BBB.m`** , I receive the **`NSString`** from **`AAA.m`** , and then call the function **`updateState`** in **`AAA.m`**.

**3.** When the **`updateState`** in **`AAA.m`** has been called from **`BBB.m`**. It set the value from **`BBB.m`** to the **`UISlider`**.

The code is like the following:

**`AAA.m`**

```
    @property (strong,nonatomic)BBB *bbb;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [self.bbb initAAA];
        [self.WhiteSlider setMinimumValue:0];
        [self.WhiteSlider setMaximumValue:100];
    }

    - (IBAction)SyncLEDState:(id)sender {

        [self.bbb readValue:@"50"];

    }
    - (void)updateState:(NSString*)state
    {
        NSlog(@"state = %@",state);
        self.WhiteSlider.value = [state intValue];;
    }
```

**`BBB.m`**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)AAA *aaa;


-(void)initAAA
{
    self.aaa = [[AAA alloc] init];
}
-(void)readValue:(NSString*)string
{
    NSlog(@"string = %@",string);
   [self.aaa updateState:string];

}
```

I already receive the value in **`updateState`** function which called by **`BBB.m`**.
But I can not update the value of **`UILabel`** or **`UISlider`** in **`AAA.m`**.

I am sure the **`UISlider`** did not has problem.

Is **`BBB.m`** create a new **`AAA.m`** due to **`self.aaa = [[AAA alloc] init];`** , so it did not change the value of **`UISlider`** at original **`AAA.m`**?

Did I missing something ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where in BBB.m are you calling `self.aaa = [[AAA alloc] init];`?

Comment: @ZeMoon In `AAA.m` , I call the function in `BBB.m` for init.

Comment: You should also set `self.aaa.bbb = self;`

Comment: @ZeMoon I try to write `self.aaa` , but it did not show `bbb` after `self.aaa`.

Comment: For that you will have to declare the property in AAA.h

Comment: @ZeMoon I have define `@property (strong,nonatomic) BBB *bbb;` in `AAA.h`. But it show `Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with ARC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BBB`creates its own private version of `AAA`in `self.aaa` that is different from the `aaa` in the call to its `readValue:`. Hence you are (presumably) updating the state of an `AAA` that is not displayed.

Alternatively, you could modify your current version approx. as follows:

in `AAA.m`:

```
self.bbb = [[BBB alloc] initWithAAA: self];
```

in `BBB.m`:

```
- (id)initWithAAA: (AAA *)aaa {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        self.aaa = aaa;
    return self;
}
```

This would make sure that both `AAA` and `BBB` refer to the same instance of `AAA`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , can you teach me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Excuse me , I add `-(void) initWithAAA:(AAA *) aaa;` in `BBB.h` , but the error show Expected a type...

Comment: I use `(void)` , because I think I don't need to return anything. I have try to change to `(id)`. But the `Expected a type` is still happen.

Comment: You have to start at the beginning and learn about Objective-C initializers! (Having said this you could also do sg. like `self.bbb.aaa = self;` in `AAA.m`).